# Depth buffer mode with several axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, axes, depth-buffer, multiple-axes, zbuffer

Is there a way to use the depth buffer while rendering a figure with two axes?

Here's the example: The figure consists of two axes, which have symmetrically inverted moving waves (for simplicity red and blue). Obviously, these waves would intersect each other, so if you look from above, you can see a red-blue field, because in some sections blue field is above the red one and the opposite in other sections.

[image: explanation]
[image: explanation]
[image: explanation]

From the images above, it is clear that the problem is in the absence of the depth buffer since the red field is being plotted after the blue one and fully overlaps it.

If I were drawing the surfs on the same axis, I could use the `SortMethod = 'depth'` option, but is it possible to sync several axes in one figure?